# Memory while printing bytes

Tags: java

Right now I am trying to print bytes from a file, it works fine in small files, but when I use files in the gigabyte range I get an exception saying "OutOfMemoryError requested array size exceeds VM" Normally I would make the array smaller but this is coming from I method that I have no control on what it outputs.

Here is original code:

```
public void convertToBytes()
    {
        try
        {
            for(byte binary:Files.readAllBytes(getCompressPath))
            {
                    System.out.println(binary);
            }
        }
        catch(IOException io)
        {
            System.out.println("An IO exception occured.");
        }
        catch(OutOfMemoryError noMemory)
        {
            System.out.println("Out of heap memory");
        }
    }//End of Method.
```

I have tried nesting loops in the for loops.
I have also tried using the ByteBuffer class like this:

```
public void convertToBytes()
{
    try
    {
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
        b.put(Files.readAllBytes(getCompressPath()));
        for(byte binary:b.array())
        {
                System.out.println(binary);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.out.println("An IO exception occured.");
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryError noMemory)
    {
        System.out.println("Out of heap memory");
    }
}//End of Method.
```

Everything I do just keeps causing the outofmemory error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read the whole file at once - open a [`FileInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) and call the [`read()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read%28%29) method to get one byte at a time.

Comment: Only one problem with that method, it does not return byte values. if I read a text file that says "abc" I should get 97,98,99,10

Comment: You're calling the no-arg version of `read()`, correct?  This returns an `int` value between 0 and 255 (i.e. the unsigned byte value) if it can read a byte from the file, and -1 if there are no more bytes.  So if called five times in succession on a four-byte file containing `abc` and a Unix line terminator it should return 97, 98, 99, 10 and -1.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you want to do? Just printing out bytes? So print them while reading without any buffer at all.

In general...do you need to load all those bytes in memory? If so you have mo chance: you need

- more memory
- adjust -Xms and -Xmx VM settings